# How to make EfCore generate COALESCE from ?? (null-coalescing) operator PER TYPE?

Tags: oracle, linq-to-sql, ef-core-5.0

My aim is to sort table (MODULE) data by its localization in other table (LOOKUP): if the asked language data is not found - fallback language ('E') is used. However, I cannot make use of `??` (null-coalescing) operator to get `COALESCE` in SQL for ALL fields at once:

```
        return moduleQueryable
            .GroupJoin(
                lookupQueryable.Where(x => x.LanguageCode == languageCode && x.Type == 'MODULETYPE'),
                x => x.ModuleTypeId,
                lookup => lookup.NumberValue,
                (b, l) => new { BaseEntity = b, LookupEntities = l }
            )
            .SelectMany(
                x => x.LookupEntities.DefaultIfEmpty(),
                (bl, lookupEntity) => new { BaseEntity = bl.BaseEntity, AskedLangLookupEntity = lookupEntity }
            )
            .GroupJoin(
                lookupQueryable.Where(x => x.LanguageCode == 'E' && x.Type == 'MODULETYPE'),
                x => x.BaseEntity.ModuleTypeId,
                lookup => moduleType.NumberValue,
                (bl, l) => new { BaseLookupEntity = bl, LookupEntities = l }
            )
            .SelectMany(
                x => x.LookupEntities.DefaultIfEmpty(),
                (bl, lookupEntity) => new { BaseLookupEntity = bl.BaseLookupEntity, FallbackLangLookupEntity = lookupEntity }
            )
            .Select(x => new { BaseEntity = x.BaseLookupEntity.BaseEntity, LookupEntity = x.BaseLookupEntity.AskedLangLookupEntity ?? x.FallbackLangLookupEntity })
            .ComplexOrderBy($"LookupEntity.{(lookupSortingField ?? "ShortName").Trim()}")
            .Select(x => x.BaseEntity);

  SELECT c.MODULEDATA1, c.MODULEDATA2, t.DATA1, t.DATA2, t0.DATA1, t0.DATA2
  FROM MODULE c
  LEFT JOIN (
      SELECT c0.DATA1, c0.DATA2
      FROM LOOKUP c0
      WHERE ((c0.TYPE = 'MODULETYPE') AND (c0.LANGUAGE = :languageCode_3))
  ) t ON c.MODULE_TYPE = t.NUMBER_VALUE
  LEFT JOIN (
      SELECT c1.C_DOMAIN, c1.C_FLD, c1.C_LANGUAGE, c1.C_STR, c1.S_COMMENT, c1.D_INS, c1.C_USR_INS, c1.S_TXT, c1.U_BA_IMAGE, c1.D_UPD, c1.C_USR_UPD, c1.C_NEOSKEY, c1.C_NUM, c1.S_TXT_INT
      FROM LOOKUP c1
      WHERE ((c0.TYPE = 'MODULETYPE') AND (c1.LANGUAGE = N'E'))
  ) t0 ON c.MODULE_TYPE = t0.NUMBER_VALUE
```

i.e. I don't get `COALESCE(t.XXX, t0.XXX)` in the generated SQL. Is there a way to get this instead of using `??` operator PER FIELD like doing the following:

```
  .Select(x => new
  {
        BaseEntity = x.BaseLookupEntity.BaseEntity,
        LookupEntity = new
        {
              Data1 = x.BaseLookupEntity.AskedLangLookupEntity.Data1 ?? x.FallbackLangLookupEntity.Data1,
              Data2 = x.BaseLookupEntity.AskedLangLookupEntity.Data2 ?? x.FallbackLangLookupEntity.Data2,
              ...,
              DataN = x.BaseLookupEntity.AskedLangLookupEntity.DataN ?? x.FallbackLangLookupEntity.DataN
        }
  }
```

The problem is that latter approach is verbose and I cannot reuse it for other entities - I have to copy-paste this code everywhere. I have tried to write extension expression method, but using anonymous type made this impossible for me.

`ComplexOrderBy($"LookupEntity.{(lookupSortingField ?? "ShortName").Trim()}")` creates expression `OrderBy(x => x.LookupEntity.[lookupSortingField])`, by default it is `OrderBy(x => x.LookupEntity.ShortName)`, `lookupSortingField` value comes from UI.

Comment: Please turn this into a [mre], esp *minimal*.

Comment: @gertarnold No problem, sure. But could you please advice where I can create online test example accessing DB (or just showing the generated SQL)? Because I am not familiar with such.

Comment: It's not about posting code as a running example. Certainly not on some external source which may disappear any time. The main thing is to remove everything that is not related to the problem. I.e. to slim down the query. The next thing is to open up black boxes like `ComplexOrderBy`, class definitions and variables that just pop up, like `lookupSortingField`. It's perfectly possible to show a query with `lookupSortingField ?? "ShortName"` and w/o all surrounding noise.

Comment: @gertarnold sorry. You're right. I've now edited my question.